# I want to display the items checked on checkedlistbox into different textboxes in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, checkedlistbox

I want to add the items checked in the checklistbox into different textboxes.
Like checklistbox item 1 checked must be added to textbox 1.
Then the next item checked that is checklistbox item 2 must be added to textbox 2. I want to do this for 4 item.
I am new to this language. I am trying to get the desired result but I am just not getting the code right.
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Could you show the code of what you've tried?

Comment: Could you provide some related code about how you 'add the items checked in the checklistbox' ? It will help others make a test.